# How to create a Radar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, radar-chart

I want to create  a radar chart from spotify dataset of an artist but when I tried to create it
using radarchart() it gives me messy one

Example Data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  danceability = c(0.286, 0.475, 0.306, 0.587, 0.549, 0.668),
  energy = c(0.150, 0.359, 0.707, 0.482, 0.457, 0.249),
  key = c(6, 5, 7, 2, 5, 9),
  loudness = c(-16.981, -11.125, -5.411, -8.427, -9.953, -10.512),
  mode = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
  speechiness = c(0.0429, 0.0622, 0.0640, 0.0409, 0.0288, 0.0424),
  acousticness = c(0.929, 0.780, 0.038, 0.695, 0.863, 0.713),
  instrumentalness = c(8.13e-01, 5.93e-06, 7.07e-03, 0.00e+00, 7.89e-02, 0.00e+00),
  liveness = c(0.4490, 0.0860, 0.1900, 0.1280, 0.0938, 0.1070),
  valence = c(0.376, 0.496, 0.526, 0.165, 0.506, 0.707)
)
```

Output of Above Code

[image]

```
radarchart(data)
```

This is output of the above code

[image]

**is it something to do with Scaling of Values?**